# Filter query on date returns no records

Tags: c#, linq, filtering

Having some query parameters allow the user to filter on dates.

I get all the records out of the database like this :

```
var query = _dbContext.Records.AsNoTracking();
```

And then I start filtering on the values the user provided :

```
if (queryParams.From != null)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.Created >= queryParams.From);
}
```

After filtering :

```
var records = 
            await Task<List<Record>>.Factory
                .StartNew(
                    () =>
                        query
                            .Skip((queryParams.PageNumber - 1) * queryParams.PageSize)
                            .Take(queryParams.PageSize)
                            .ToList());
```

If I give a 'From' date it always return 0 records but when I do the query directly in SQL with the 'From' date I get records. What am I missing?

Comment: What data type is `From`?  I'm guessing that it's a string, and `Created` is a `DateTime`.  If you want to do a proper comparison, you need to convert `From` to a `DateTime`.

Comment: That `Task.Factory.Startnew` came really surprisingly. What's that for?

Comment: @RobertHarvey it is a 'DateTime' (public DateTime? From { get; set; })

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods To await and convert to a list and use pagination, how would you do it?

Comment: Linq has a `ToListAsync` method.  Prefer that to starting a new Task.

Comment: `ToListAsync`. Startnew is very rarely really needed and definitely not here.

Comment: Note that `DateTime?` and `DateTime` *are not the same type.*  You might still need a cast or conversion.

Comment: @RobertHarvey x.Created and queryParams.From are both type 'DateTime?'

Comment: Good point about the ToListAsync!

Comment: What page is requested? Are all results skipped over perhaps?

Comment: Default page and I commented the paginating lines and no records...

Comment: And also without the date filter you get results?

Comment: Yes then I get results

Comment: Well, you're going to have to do some troubleshooting.  Check the values you're getting in `From` and `Created`.  You can use the debugger to step through your Linq query to see these values.

Comment: It's kind of weird, but yes, I would suspect the second snippet. But without being able to debug it in vivo, it's hard to tell. It _looks_ ok  on first glance, but somehow it _must_ be the culprit.

Comment: Sorry guys I'm an idiot, I have another filter and because of that filter in combination with the date I provided it returned logically no records. Sorry to waste your time

Comment: Haha. We've all been there. At least you heard about ToListAsync now.